# What is the effect of capacitors at OpAmp input -frequency response?

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, transfer-function

I want to filter noise at opamp inputs. For this purpose I am planning to place \$C_p\$ and \$C_n\$ capacitors near opamp input pins as you see in the image.

[image]

What happens if
1. \$V_{IN}\$ is fixed DC voltage? Does the basic inverting and non-inverting amplifier formulas differ?
2. \$V_{IN}\$ is sinusiodal? What is the formula of \$V_{OUT}\$ in terms of resistor and capacitor values in both circuits?

Answer (score 4):

In the left hand circuit you are not filtering noise rather, you are amplifying high frequencies because Cn is in parallel with R2. It should be noted that Cp might be able to filter noise if your input voltage was fed via a resistor to +Vin.

In the right hand circuit, theoretically (perfect op-amp) you are doing nothing because Cn connects to a virtual earth and Cp is shorted out.

As for working out the basic formulas, if you were so bold as to propose the circuits as noise filters then you ought to consider doing a bit of research into why they are wrong.

Comment: Cn on the right side does nothing to the signal, but increases the noise gain at high frequencies